# Visual Studio T4 template replace text in class file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

I will like to know how I can create a T4 template that can find and replace a string in a class file.

For example:
I have a class file called "Test.cs" that is auto-generated by some other process.
I would like to run a T4 template against the "Test.cs" file that will rename all "OldText" text it finds to "NewText"

Test.cs BEFORE T4 template has ran.

```
public class OldText 
{ 
    public OldText() {} 
}
```

Test.cs AFTER T4 template has ran.

```
public class NewText 
{ 
    public NewText() {} 
}
```

Comment: This is not what T4 is for. This is what VS addins or Roslyn syntaxwalkers would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jeroen pointed out, this is not what t4 templates are for. However, you may consider writing a t4 template which would generate Test.cs for you where the actual class name would be stored in a variable. Your Test.tt could look like this:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    var className = "OldText";
#>
using System;

public class <#= className #>
{ 
    public <#= className #>() {} 
}
```

Then, to generate Test.cs with class name NewText you would just change value of `className` variable in one single place.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not just the class name.  The T4 template is a OData template that Microsoft created and in incorrectly generates the NameSpace.ClassName when pulling the metadata from the OData service.

Comment: @goroth is it [this extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937) which you are talking about? Have you perhaps tried asking for a fix in Q&A section?

Comment: I have posted several bugs to thier site but they are not very good at responding.

Comment: Do you have access to the OData template file? Can you modify it to do what you want?

Comment: Other than that roslyn is probably the way to go as jeroen suggested.